# printing number from html tag in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi I have been trying to get the time data from this website: https://clockofeidolon.com (hours, minutes, seconds) and tried to use beautifulsoup to print contents of '*span class="big*' tags since the time information is kept there and I have come up with this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import Session

session = Session()
session.headers['user-agent'] = (
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
    'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/'
    '66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'
)

url = 'https://clockofeidolon.com'
response = session.get(url=url)

data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
spans = soup.find_all('<span class="big')

print([span.text for span in spans])
```

But the output only shows "[]" and nothing else. How would I go about printing the number in each of the 3 tags?

Comment: I think the class=big-* tags are populated through javascript. So Beautiful soup wont find anything. You need to use Selenium for example.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned by @AndrejKesely bs4 will not be able to do anything here as the dom tree does not hold the text and it is updated by JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned this can be achieved with selenium once you have the correct [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) installed the following should get you on the right track:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://clockofeidolon.com')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

spans = soup.find_all(class_='big-hour')
for span in spans:
        print(span.text)



driver.quit()
```